# Dados PHP em documento Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa tarde.

Tenho o seguinte código em PHP, um tanto quanto simples:

```
<?
    include("conexao.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("select top 1 * from grafico_tb order by data_referencia desc");
    $dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $dados['perc1'];
    $dados['perc2'];
?>
```

E tenho o seguinte código em javascript: `grafico.js`

```
initSparklineCharts: function() {
    if (!jQuery().sparkline) {
            return;
        }
    $("#sparkline_bar").sparkline([8, 9], {
                type: 'bar',
                width: '100',
                barWidth: 5,
                height: '55',
                barColor: '#f36a5b',
                negBarColor: '#e02222'
            });
};
```

No lugar do "8" e do "9", eu pretendia jogar as variáveis criadas dentro do documento `.php`.
Já tentei criar este mesmo gráfico dentro da tag `<script></script>` em um `.php` da seguinte forma:

```
initSparklineCharts: function() {
    if (!jQuery().sparkline) {
            return;
        }
    $("#sparkline_bar").sparkline([<? $dados['perc1'].','.$dados['perc2']?>], {
                type: 'bar',
                width: '100',
                barWidth: 5,
                height: '55',
                barColor: '#f36a5b',
                negBarColor: '#e02222'
            });
};
```

E também com o `echo` na frente das variáveis mas não deu certo. Alguma solução?

*O gráfico funciona com os valores "8" e "9" sem ser variáveis e as variáveis em php também funcionam.*

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

testa isso aqui no lugar do seu php

```
<?PHP print("$dados[perc1] , $dados[perc2]"); ?>
```

vai ficar assim

```
initSparklineCharts: function() {
    if (!jQuery().sparkline) {
            return;
        }
    $("#sparkline_bar").sparkline([<?PHP print("$dados[perc1] , $dados[perc2]"); ?>], {
                type: 'bar',
                width: '100',
                barWidth: 5,
                height: '55',
                barColor: '#f36a5b',
                negBarColor: '#e02222'
            });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser jogar o PHP dentro de um arquivo JS. Você vai criar um arquivo PHP e colocar como saída APLICATION/JAVASCRIPT em um HEADER. Ficara assim: grafico.php

Answer (score 0):

João eu uso um plugin de gráficos parecido, mas a aplicação é a mesma no seu modelo também segue o meu exemplo:

```
[<?php
 $sql = "SELECT...";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['data'].",";
  }
 ?>]
```